# Create a PDF document using just VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf

Is it possible to create (set formatting, add text by form etc) a PDF document in VB.NET without using any third party libraries?  This would be done in a website.

Comment: Do you want this to be with libraries included with .NET or is free fine? How do you define what you are looking for?

Comment: If you *really* want to do with without using third-party libraries, be prepared for some serious reading up and coding to implement the PDF Specification (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html)!

Answer (score 3):

I know you said w/o a third party control, but maybe **free** will work ... but I'll just throw this out there just in case in proves to be informational.

We have to do the same thing in our environment ... and we opted to just use Crystal Reports (which you have a license to with Visual Studio) and leverage the export to PDF functionality. Allows us to deliver **pretty** forms and lists to the customer.

I'm not a big fan of Crystal Reports, for a variety of reasons ... but it was easy to implement and at no additional cost to our end customer.

Comment: Microsoft Reporting Services also has a functionality to export to PDF.

Comment: Crystal Reports and Microsoft Reporting Services are not only free but also supported (a possible objection to other third-party components)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with iTextSharp, which is technically third-party (but it's free):

http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Creating_PDF_documents_in.aspx

Here are some more options:

http://www.aspnetworld.com/articles/2004011801.aspx

Comment: I have used iTextSharp as well, it's not too difficult to use and is very full-featured for PDF generation