# Generating Barcode into PDF document using Asp.net (VB.Net) or Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, pdf, barcode

using ***(asp.Net)VB.Net*** Or ***JavaScript*** , what is the best way to generate **Bar-code** In **PDF** document for a web application  and print it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BarcodeLibrary.aspx?fid=470627&fr=26) which creates a barcode image.

Then have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566591/create-a-pdf-document-using-just-vb-net) about how to create a PDF in .NET

Combine the two and you should have a solution.